# Is this pseudo-derivative END function executable?

Tags: assembly, architecture

Consider the below Assembly code using x86 assembler.

---

```
      MOV  R1, 40;
      MOV  R2, 1A;
LAB 1 CALL SUB1;
      SHL  R2;
      DEC  R3;
      CMP  R1, R2;
      JNE  LAB1;
      END;

SUB1  PUSH R1;
      MOV  R3, 4F;
LAB2  DEC  R3;
      CMP  R1, R3;
      JLE  LAB2;

      POP  R1;
      RET;
```

---

Is `END` an executable instruction? If yes, why? Hindsight tells me that it is however I can't seem to figure out quite a valid explanation for it.

---

Also, how does the `JNE LAB1` command work in this context? If *what* is not equal to `LAB1`?

Comment: Please confirm whether this is 80x86 assembler.

Comment: Please add architecture tag and specify assembler. In general conditional jumps consult the flags, so in this case the `JNE` applies to the previous `CMP R1, R2`. The `LAB1` is the target of the jump. `END` may be an alias for `RET`.

Comment: @abligh - No information other than the one given above is provided, kindly proceed with 80x86 in mind

Comment: @lurker - So that means that this examination question is somewhat incorrect or not presented properly?

Comment: @Juxhin I think the point is that this *is* an examination question. This syntax doesn't match any existing assembly, so the whole thing will never execute. Asking if END is an existing instruction is pointless, nothing is real here. END is probably just to tell that the program terminate here.

Comment: @ElderBug Good point, will keep that in mind. Just wasn't sure when comparing this past examination question to some Assembly code I found online which is why I requested clarification. (Hope this helps the down-voters understand the point behind my post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As instructed, I have assumed it works like an x86 instruction set and `masm` or a `masm` compatible assembler. Note it can't actually be an x86 instruction set as without more `R1`, `R2` etc. are not registers. If you want to know exactly what it does, you'll need to tell us which processor.

Normally (i.e. in `masm` etc) END is an assembler directive and not an instruction:

> `END (END PROCEDURE)`
>   The `END` directive is put after the last statement of a program to tell the assembler that this is the end of the program module. The assembler will ignore any statements after an END directive, so you should make sure to use only one END directive at the very end of your program module. A carriage return is required after the `END` directive.

Your `END` directive is not the last statement of the program, which (assuming `masm` and `x86`) is incorrect.

In another instruction set, `END` might do something else (e.g. halt the processor). Without knowing which instruction set, we have no way of knowing.

The `JNE` instruction tests the `Z` flag and jumps (to LAB1) if it is clear. The `Z` flag is set (or cleared) by the previous `CMP` instruction (set if the operands are equal, else cleared). It thus jumps if the operands are not equal.

Comment: `cmp R1, R2` wouldn't be a valid instruction in x86 since neither `R1` or `R2` are x86 registers unless they've been `TEXTEQU` as such (`R1 TEXTEQU ax` for example). Also, in the context of the OP's example, `END` is not being placed after the last statement of the program, so this can't be a proper use of `END`.

Comment: The comment for `JNE LAB1` is, "jump if not equal to LAB1", is this correct? As I found it somewhat confusing.

Comment: @Juxhin yes - it jumps to LAB1

Comment: Thanks alot @abligh - does make more sense now :-)

Comment: @lurker well yes, I'm just assuming it works like x86 which is what the OP asked. It's a bit hard to tell exactly what assembler will do without knowing which assembly - I'm sure we could invent one where `JNE` jumped if nearly equal or something.

Comment: In the context, it can't work as you're describing since `END` isn't placed in the instruction sequence in a way required by the definition given by MASM. It would probably yield a syntax error if one attempted to assemble it with the `END` in the middle of a sequence of executable instructions.

Comment: @lurker that was exactly my point - as I said, the placement of the `END` statement is incorrect for x86 masm (which OP asked us to assume).

Answer (score 1):

In this context:

```
  ...
  CMP  R1, R2;
  JNE  LAB1;
  END;
  ...
```

Regarding `JNE`, the prior `CMP R1, R2` would internally subtract `R1 - R2` or `R2 - R1` (depending upon architecture) and set internal CPU flags accordingly (*e.g.*, zero, sign, overflow, carry). `JNE LAB1` will do a jump to `LAB1` if the result of the subtraction was not zero.

You'd have to say that `END` is executable (either directly as an instruction, or translated as a macro in whatever language is being used). This is because the `JNE` prior might choose not to take the jump and, therefore, the CPU could attempt to execute `END`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @lurker - did indeed clarify the question :-)

Comment: @lurker Perhaps a typo? `JNE LAB1`will do a jump to LAB1 if the result of the subtraction was **not** zero.

Comment: @user3144770 oops, yes, thank you! I fixed my explanatory text.